# Crm 2011 - default entity document location

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

Hi I have two document locations for each Service Activity and I wonder if I can set the default one?

Now the default view is "Confidential documents" but I'd rather like if it would be Documents. What this default location depends on ?

[image]